# dxTagbox not working with data bind which is using on a popup

Tags: jquery, html, devextreme

I am using a `dxTagBox` on a popup for add details. When we open that popup then the tagbox is rendering properly but data-source(data not showing) are not binding. There is no console error, while the same things working fine on a simple aspx page.

Why is this happening? Are we missing something or is there any other way to solve that?

```
var implist  = $("#impId")
       .dxTagBox({
           placeholder: "(All)",
           dataSource: data,
           searchEnabled: true,
           showClearButton: true,
           showSelectionControls: true,
           hideSelectedItems: true
       }).dxTagBox("instance");
```

Comment: I've prepared a simple [example](https://codepen.io/Doka/pen/BVZpxJ) that renders dxTagBox within dxPopup but cannot reproduce the issue with it. Can you modify the example to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I am not using dx popup, just rendering tagbox with div in html model(query popup) and that model  showing on button click.

Comment: Would you please share your code of query popup?